# Какая идея оптимального решения

Tags: c++, массивы

Дано два массива A и B, заполненными
числами, и третий массив индексов
позиций I.
Реализовать функцию, которая меняет
местами элементы в первых двух
массивах по индексам, записанным в
третий массив I. Размерности
массивов A и B могут отличаться.

Вообще ничего не понимаю в массивах, помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: К элементам массива можно обратиться с помощью синтаксиса `A[i]` — это i-й элемент массива A. Для решения данной задачи этого, в общем-то, достаточно. А теперь решение за вами: если вы начинаете писать код самостоятельно, то, уверен, вы получите помощь. Если нет и ждете, что кто-то сделает задание за вас и ошибочно называете это помощью — думаю, вопрос будет быстро закрыт...

Comment: Нет, как раз мне и нужно было понять принцип! Спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.